# Delegation syntax

Tags: php

```
$var = Foo::bar('aaa', 'bbb')
      ->add('something', AnyClass::instance($var, 'something'));
```

`Foo::bar()` returns its object, `add()` does something and takes as a second argument a new class. This class needs the current Foo object.

Is there a way to do this without separating it into two statements?Foo::bar().

Comment: No, there isn't. Store the object in a variable and use it (why don't you want to do it in two statements?)

Comment: Why make it more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: I just think this syntax is a bit more readable.

Comment: I think most users will disagree with the 'more readable' statement.

Comment: I thought there is some magical way to do this, but if there's not then I'll stay with dividing this, thanks :P

Answer (score 1):

Some other languages let you say something like

```
(var = Foo::bar('aaa', 'bbb'))->add(...);
```

(with the assignment part in parentheses).  Unfortunately (at least as of 5.3), PHP's parser is rather crappy in that regard, and freaks out when you try.

So it looks like you have to either break it up into two statements, or `return $this` from the `add` method.

Short of that, the best i could come up with off the top of my head is

```
call_user_func(array($var = Foo::bar('aaa', 'bbb'), 'add'), 'something', ...);
```

which i don't think anyone would consider more readable.  :P